# Error when compiling on my device in Xcode (iPhone 6-plus)

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

first I want to say that I had an iPhone 5 and i had no problems testing my apps on Xcode the set up was very easy, a few days ago I changed it to an iPhone 6-plus. I got errors while trying to test my apps on the new phone, what I did was go to iOS development>member center>Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles>Devices and I added my device there, I don't know if that is correctly I would like if someone could tell me the correct way to set up a new device on xCode, but at least I can run a few apps now.

I was building an app that uses "Parse", when I run it on iPhone 6 Simulator i have no problems,it works fine, when I try to run it on my device I got this error:

**"(application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@, Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "falta la clave de autorización “aps-environment” válida para la aplicación" UserInfo=0x17007dc80 {NSLocalizedDescription=falta la clave de autorización “aps-environment” válida para la aplicación})
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) "**

and it point me this line:

```
->  0x1003b9474 <+44>:  brk    #0x1
```

(with a little pop up that says "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1003e9474))

========

And when I try to run it on a iPhone 6-plus Simulator I get this error:

**Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)**

and it point my this code

```
 query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
```

Comment: You are probably trying to register for push notification somewhere in your app and push notifications are not supported by the simulator, in the phone the error is because you didn't register your app to use push notifications

Comment: Thanks and how do i register my app for push notifications?

Comment: Also, you should check to see if it's currentuser of objectId that is nil.  My initial assumption is that since this is a new device, you haven't logged in yet and so currentUser doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly as it says, and it's more that you have a new device than anything specific with the iPhone 6+.

First, in the Simulator you get the error because you can't send push notifications to the Simulator, only real devices.

On your real device, it's quite possibly the same issue, though this time I would speculate it's because you've not granted the app permission to receive notifications. Either way the error is the same: you're using an *optional* value, assuming that it contains something useful when, in fact, it's nil. Without any code it's difficult to be more specific than that.

Incidentally, picking the very top of the stack trace is not terribly useful. You need to keep going down the stack until you find some of your own code.

Answer (score 0):

To set your application to use push notification you will need to go to [iOS Development Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/) and set your app to be able to use it.

There is a good tutorial with all the steps you need [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925) but remember even after that the push notification will work only in real iOS devices and not simulator.